# SwiftUI: View does not fully update, lags behind when its @ObservedObject is updated from parent?

Tags: ios, swiftui, observedobject

I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @State var selectedItemMOID:NSManagedObjectID?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                if let selectedItemMOID = selectedItemMOID, let item = viewContext.object(with: selectedItemMOID) as? Item {
                    ItemView(item: item)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        if let item = addItem() {
                            selectedItemMOID = item.objectID
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() -> Item? {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
                return newItem
            } catch {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    
}





struct ItemView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var item:Item
    @State var itemIDString:String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            
            VStack {
                
                Text(itemIDString)
                
                Text("the item: \(item.objectID)")
                
            }
            .onChange(of: item, perform: { newValue in
                updateIdString()
            })
            .onAppear {
                updateIdString()
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func updateIdString() {
        
        itemIDString = "\(item.objectID)"
    }
    
    
}
```

**Problem**:

when I press the plus button (top right), `ItemView` **partially** updates. The bottom Text view updates immediately, the top one lags behind.

See this behavior:

[image]

**You can see the item id at top is always one behind** (except first render).
So, for example, hit plus (after first time) and top is p45, bottom, p46. And so on.

Why is the top Text lagging one behind?

I added the `onChange` as well, thinking that would sync things up, but it didn't. Without it, the top Text never updates after first item is set.

```
    .onChange(of: item, perform: { newValue in
        updateIdString()
    })
```

I need to understand why this is happening so I can understand how to properly build views in general that use `@ObservedObject`s, so things update immediately when the ObservedObject is set to a new one.

So, to be clear my question is how to fix this code so that the entire `ItemView` updates immediately when `item` is set on it and **why this is happening** at a high level so I can avoid this same type of mistake going forward.

To address **Asperi's** approach (thanks for your answer!):

His answers fixes this specific case, but, I am not sure how I would go about using that pattern. For example, if `ItemView` observes multiple objects, lets say a `Car` and a `User` entity, then `.id(car.id)` would only react to setting a new `Car` on `ItemView` and not react to setting a new `User` necessarely. So, then, what is the point of `@ObservedObject` in this context. With the suggested `.id(car.id)` it would only react to one and not the other (or many more if `ItemView` had like 6 @ObservedObjects...).

Does this mean a view should only have one @ObservedObject? I wouldn't think so. Am I wrong?

Just trying to understand how to scale the `id(item.id)` pattern if it's the agreeable answer. I don't understand yet.

Comment: Are you updating the observed object on the main thread?

Comment: yes. just tested again. removed the `withAnimation...` also. Breakpoint shows always on main.

Comment: What exactly are you accomplishing? I don't understand what the end goal of this is? Item objectID isn't even initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is due to reuse/caching, in short rendering optimisation, try

```
    List {
       // content is here
    }
    .id(item)     // << this one !!
```

Comment: this "makes things work" in this specific case, but I am trying to also address the other half of the question. See question edits. Thank you.

Comment: both approaches work. Asperi answered first... Both helped me understand the why which is laid out in the comments... thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't use the newValue, change it to:

```
.onChange(of: item, perform: { newValue in
    itemIDString = "\(newValue.objectID)"
})
```

Comment: same problem. I tried this and it still lags.

Comment: Please try the new code

Comment: ok, so, I did this and it worked. So, can you explain why? It seems like newValue is set to the latest I pass in to `ItemView` before `item` on `ItemView` is set? I think understanding what and when things update in this context will answer the other half of the question.

Comment: I just read this: `The new value is passed into the closure. The previous value may be captured by the closure to compare it to the new value. For example, in the following code example, PlayerView passes both the old and new values to the model.` That is in the Xcode docs... So, it seems like `@ObservedObject var item:Item` is set after this closure is called? Am I reading this right?

Comment: So then `updateIdString()` is run by the `onChange` call before `item` has a chance to update.

Comment: onChange captures the old value in the block